# React context not updating on certain places

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, use-state, use-context

On button click I'am adding product information to local storage and setting it to context.

I'm using context in two places - header and products page, syntax is almost the same. There is a console.log in header and whenever i'am interacting with context it's instantly firing, confirming that context is working fine. However, when i enter products page i need to reload it one more time in order to get the data. Why is that?

Context file

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export const LikedContext = React.createContext([{}, () => {}]);

export const LikedProvider = (props) => {
  const [liked, setLiked] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      let likedData = localStorage.getItem("liked");

      likedData = likedData ? JSON.parse(likedData) : "";
      setLiked(likedData);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <LikedContext.Provider value={[liked, setLiked]}>
      {props.children}
    </LikedContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Header

```
export const LikedProductsIcon = () => {
  const [liked, setLiked] = useContext(LikedContext);
  console.log("liked header", liked);

  const likedCount =
    null !== liked && Object.keys(liked).length ? liked.totalProductsCount : "";
  const totalPrice =
    null !== liked && Object.keys(liked).length ? liked.totalProductsPrice : "";

  return (
    <>
      <CartContainer to="/pamegti-produktai">
        <CountCircle>
          <HeartSvg />
          {likedCount ? <span>{likedCount}</span> : ""}
        </CountCircle>
      </CartContainer>
    </>
  );
};
```

Liked products page

```
const LikedProducts = () => {
  const [liked, setLiked] = useContext(LikedContext);

  console.log("liked page", liked);

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Container>
        {liked ? (
          liked.products.map((product, index) => (
            <ProductsCard product={product} blackText />
          ))
        ) : (
          <div>Pamėgtų produktų nėra.</div>
        )}
      </Container>
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

Comment: Where is the `<LikedProvider>` being rendered in the component tree, relative to `<LikedProducts>` and `<LikedProductsIcon>`? It sounds like the Provider is an ancestor of one, but not the other. It needs to be an ancestor of both.

Comment: Products page is using `LikedProvider` in app.js file and `LikedProductsIcon` is using it in Layout. Seems to be fine as both files are giving me data just one of them needs a reload to do so.

Comment: `Products page is using LikedProvider in app.js file and LikedProductsIcon is using it in Layout. ` So you're rendering **two** `<LikedProvider>`s?

Comment: Yes, I'am rendering two `<LikedProvider>`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you render multiple `<LikedProviders>`, then they will each have their own independent state. Setting state in one of them will not affect the other one. The reason they sync up when you refresh the page is that they both load from local storage and see the same value. But that only happens on load, and they will get out of sync after that.

If you want the state to be shared, then you want to just render one of them. Place it at the top of your component tree (app.js is a good spot) so that it's accessible by all the components that need it, and delete the other one.

Comment: So whats the solution if i want to use same context in two places? If I am wrapping Layout in `LikedProvider` it works only on header but not the page, even though that page is wrapped in layout.

Comment: `So whats the solution if i want to use same context in two places?` You don't need multiple providers in order to use it in multiple places. Put a single provider at the top of your app, then call `useContext(LikedContext)` in every component that needs it. useContext will look up the component tree to find the nearest provider, and give you the value from that. If you just have one provider, and it's far enough up the tree to be an ancestor of every component that needs it, then every component will be using that same provider.